# iPhone application development adding subview in viewbased application

Tags: iphone

I am having a scrollview and above the scrollview am having 6 view(6 subviews over the scrollview)each views have lables.How to add all these views in to my application am used interface builder to design these view.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the interface builder, and drag the six views to the scroll view.